# In django how do I add another instance to an inline model before saving it?

Tags: python, django

I have a parent model with inline details model. While saving the inline model details, how do I add a new detail record before saving the entire record i.e parent and its details? Example: models.py:

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now().date())
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

class VoucherDetail(models.Model):
    voucher = models.ForeignKey(Voucher,blank=True,null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=9,default=0,
                                       blank=True,null=True)
    narration = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=9,default=0,
                                       blank=True,null=True)
```

Before saving a Voucher, I would like to add the amount totals of the formset and **create another entry in voucher detail**

with some narration and the **total amount**

I need a complete code sample for the same.  Using django 1.6.5, Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method in parent model admin and do the necessary calculation to achieve the same:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        for d in obj.voucherdetail_set.all():
            if d.value:
                amt_exists = True                    
                pass
            else:
                amt_exists =False

    if amt_exists is False:
        try:
            dr_detail = VoucherDetail()
            dr_detail.voucher = Voucher.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
            dr_detail.narration = "Client remarks"

            dr_detail......
            dr_detail.save()
        except Exception,e:
            print e
    obj.save()
```